# Migrating combined forms/windows authentication in asp.net WebForms application to asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application written in asp.net where I am performing combined forms/windows authentication. I am wanting to replicate this method of authentication in an asp.MVC / webAPI application and, being an MVC novice, was after some advice.

First up, the reason that we are using this mix of authentication is to support a mixture of individual / generic logons and to allow a user using a PC logged on as a different windows user to still be able to enter their logon credentials to access the system whilst the system will log them on automatically if they are logged on to their PC using their windows credentials (I hope that made sense!).

I understand that using session variables in MVC is frowned upon as it breaks the RESTful principles, but I can't work out a better way of handling the mixed logon requirements. I'd thought about a custom membership provider but this seems overkill & I can't see it working for 'generic' accounts that may be logged on on multiple PC's.

Currently, in the global.asax session_start event I am first looking for something in request.servervariables("LOGON_USER"), this is populated when windows authentication is on and anon authentication is off on IIS. If this is found then I create an instance of a 'user' class and call a method to authenticate them based solely on their windows logon. If they authenticate OK then I store a 'currentUser' object in the session that is used throughout the application.

If there is no LOGON_USER (or if a different user is requested in the querystring) then I look for Request.QueryString("User") and Request.QueryString("Password") in the request. If both are present then an instance of a 'user' class is created and a method called to authenticate using the username/password. If they authenticate OK then I store a 'currentUser' object in the session that is used throughout the application.

If the authentication fails then the user is redirected to the logon page.

Any idea how I would achieve this in MVC? How do I perform redirects? Is there a more 'MVC' way of doing this?

Thanks for any advice,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is appropriate to store session data in a RESTful application. The important thing is that it isn't created by any side effects from other actions.

You can use a UserSession controller with get and post Login actions. The get provides a view with the username and password form and a "login with windows" button.

If a username and password are provided, the post action can verify the details and create a current user object to store in the session.  If the login with windows button is pressed, the current user object can tag that windows identity should be used.

To ensure that other controllers are properly authenticated, you would need a custom authorization filter to check that there is a valid user attached to the request.

If you're willing to use ASP.NET MVC 5, there are both authentication and authorization filters. That would make what you're trying to do a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Simon. OK, so storing a 'current User' in the session is good to go with - that can then be used with a custom authorisation filter that examines this session object (I take it that's relatively easy to plug in so that it's used when a controller method is decorated with <authorise>?). For the Windows authentication I wan't it to 'just work' i.e. When a session starts it has a windows logon, finds the relevant user in the database and creates the Current User object to store in the session. Is global.asax session_start still the best place to do this?

Comment: The check for an existing windows login should be another action on the usersession controller. The Authorize filter should redirect to that action.

Comment: OK, I have implemented a custom membership provider. Using Forms authentication the GET Logon() Controller Action looks for the LOGON_USER server variable: if it finds one it uses this to authenticate the user: otherwise the user has the logon form displayed.

Comment: Only question left - say a user accesses the site, it recognises their windows logon and logs them in. Say this was linked to a generic windows logon and a system admin then want's to come along and do system admin stuff with their own logon: if they try and log out this will immediately log them back in so, without logging out of windows, they can't switch user. Any ideas of how to ge around this?

Comment: It would need a switch user action. Something that displays the form and overrides the use of the windows authentication to create the current user.